# Add anotations to a pdf

Tags: android

I want to add an annotation to a pdf file,like marking a line of text in the pdf with yellow color.I would like to know if this is possible in android or not.If yes a code sample or a link will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible through Android's API, and there is not even a free third-party java library you can use.

The only possibilities are:

- Use a `WebView` and [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)
- Use the commercial [`PDFTron` library](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/android_pdf_library.html)
- Write your own solution
- Port an existing C++ solution using the NDK
- Open the file in another app that has the needed capabilities (e.g. Adobe Reader)